# Excel formula to use values from one table with comma separated values in another table

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to use the values from Table 1 to populate Table 2 automatically but I am getting errors when I tried to use vlookup or the filter function. This is based on the fact that I am using full name (last name, first name). Is there a a better way to solve this problem?

Vlookup Formula: =VLOOKUP(G3,$A$3:$B$7,2,FALSE)
Filter Formula: =TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(B:B,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A:A,FILTERXML("**"&SUBSTITUTE(G3&", ",", ","****")&"**","//b"),0))))[image]

[image]

Comment: Why tag Excel-2010? Have you looked into TEXTSPLIT instead FILTERXML?

Comment: Tried it but it's giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
Formula F3: =IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10);FALSE;VLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(E3;;CHAR(10);TRUE;1);$A$3:$B$7;2;FALSE));"")
```

[image]

Comment: I used this but I got an error message. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: @SammieDave did you replace semicolon with comma?

Comment: I changed it and now the output is blank.....=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),FALSE,VLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(E3,,CHAR(10),TRUE,1),$A$3:$B$7,2,FALSE)),"")

Comment: @SammieDave you also need to adjust the formula to your need. My names are in column E. Yours might be in G

Comment: Edited accordingly. Any idea why it could be displaying blank results?

Comment: @SammieDave difficult to say because I can't see. You need Linebreaks in table 2 column name. You can evaluate the different parts of the formula to see where the error is

Comment: see screenshot using the formula you sent over. It's producing a blank output

Comment: @SammieDave The formula seems right. Maybe you have extra spaces after the names? You can try this formula to eliminate extra spaces or remove them =IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10);FALSE;VLOOKUP(TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(G3;;CHAR(10);TRUE;1));TRIM(A:B);2;FALSE));"")